# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_1})\cdots(1+\frac{1}{a_n})$, where $a_1=1$, $a_n=n(1+a_{n-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_1})(1+\frac{1}{a_2})\cdots(1+\frac{1}{a_n})$,
>   where $a_1 = 1$, $a_n = n(1+a_{n-1})$

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{a_1}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{a_2}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{a_1} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdots \frac{1}{n} \cdot (a_n + 1) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n + 1}{n!}.
\end{align*}

Then I'm stuck. How to proceed?

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A007526](https://oeis.org/A007526). The OEIS entry has much information including the limit you want to find.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that
$$a_n=n+na_{n-1}$$
$$a_n=n+n(n-1)+n(n-1)a_{n-2}$$
and so on, giving us eventually
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}$$
Now we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(a_n+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=e$$

Comment: Not $e+1$.  The sum for $e$ includes the term with $0!$ as denominator.

Comment: @OscarLanzi oops! Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Show by induction that

$a_1=1!/0!$

$a_2=2!/0!+2!/1!$

$a_3=3!/0!+3!/1!+3!/2!$

...

$\color{blue}{a_n=n!/0!+n!/1!+n!/2!+...+n!/(n-1)!}$

Thereby the limit is $1/0!+1/1!+2/2!+...1/n!+...=e$.

Answer (score 1):

From where you stuck you can proceed as
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n+1}{n!}&=\frac{a_n}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(a_{n-1}+1)+\frac{1}{n!}=\\
&=\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}=\ldots=
1+\frac{1}{1!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}.
\end{align}